# Как получить последний запрос mysqli не имея идентификатора

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Я использую запрос

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'users%'
```

Таблицы имеют вид users00001, users00002 И так далее.
Есть ли возможность как-то получить последнюю созданную таблицу, к примеру users01234. Проблема в том, что на выходе нет идентификаторов.
Возможно ли это вообще, или какие могут быть решения?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: чисто из логики sql отсортировать в обратном порядке и вывести самую перву. Но как это сделать именно с таблицами я не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
SELECT table_name, table_rows 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'forumNet' AND TABLE_NAME like "user%"
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME DESC LIMIT 1
```

Где `forumNet` - название вашей БД